# Delphi - read content that is loaded dynamically

Tags: delphi

I want to read the content (html) of a certain URL. I send a GET command, receive the html and I do what I want to do with it, no problem here.

The problem happens when a site loads more info into itself when you scroll down (like Facebook does), so the content I receive is the default one without the parts that are yet to be loaded. Any idea what can be done to retrieve the next parts automatically so I can read more and more of the content of such site?

I saw something about phantomJS but I'm developing a desktop application (using Delphi) so I can't use it. Thanks.

Comment: You would have to look at the HTML to find out how it is loading the content. Such as client-side scripting, maybe mixed with AJAX. Discover the new URLs and download them as needed.

Comment: Check what is posted to the site when you scroll down. Maybe you will find a sort of `page_no` parameter in the URL. But this is specific to the site implementation.

Comment: When a site loads content _on its own_ then it uses JavaScript triggered by different events based on mouse clicks, scrolling, keyboard shortcuts, time etc. If you want the content _to be alive_ then you need to execute the JavaScripts of it in a JS execution engine and trigger events on your own. I don't know what you are exactly trying to do but it definitely feels wrong.

Comment: Why do you think desktop applications can't use PhantomJS? PhantomJS is a desktop application, after all.

Comment: You could write a browser, that would work!